# Prevent Google analytics from creating a page view on outbound link click event

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Whenever I am trying to click on outbound link and sending the event to google analytics , GA is creating a new page view. In my case it should be recorded in event tracking section only. Not sure how to prevent Google analytics from creating a page view on outbound link click event.

Here is my js code which is called on every outbound link click.

```
ga('send', 'event', {
    eventCategory: 'Outbound Link',
    eventAction: 'click',
    eventLabel: event.target.href,
    transport: 'beacon'
});
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: GA usually does not do this, and the code you posted does not explain how this happens. Can you share an URL where you see this happening?

Comment: @EikePierstorff here the code  :$(document).on("click", "[data-role=\"footer\"] a", function (e) {
   ga('send', 'event', {
      eventCategory: 'Outbound Link',
      eventAction: 'click',
      eventLabel: event.target.href,
      transport: 'beacon'
    });    
}); now this js function is invoked every time a link is clicked and send event is sent to google. but the issue is under real time a new page view is created by GA. I need this to track it under event tracking only.

Comment: Oh, I tripped over that too. Realtime view displays an additional hit because the event tag still sends a document location field, but this will not be part of the permanent reports. So no worries.

Comment: @EikePierstorff got your point . But is there any way to prevent that ?

Comment: Not without wrecking your permanent records (removing the location from the event means you can no longer tell on which page the event occured).

Comment: would you be able to explain a bit . how can I remove the location from ga('send', 'event', ) .